# How to dress for PhD interview at US institution

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, interview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dressing etiquette for interviews in academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1680/dressing-etiquette-for-interviews-in-academia)

I have been invited for a PhD interview day at an institution in the US. I was just wondering how formal/informal these interview days are. I know I will be meeting a few professors for which I have expressed interest. I definitely do not want to be underdressed but also I do not want to overdoit. Especially because I have noticed in my field ecology/biology the dress code is quite loose. (I remember this colleague of mine that would come to work with a shirt full of paint stains because he was painting his house, that cracked me up every time)

Would nice pants, a buttoned shirt, and elegant black sneakers be good enough? Should I wear a blazer as well?

Comment: This is much more specific and also country specific. Also using the search function I was not able to locate the question you mentioned. Perhaps we can improve the tagging of the other question.

Comment: The answer to the question quoted by @EnergyNumbers is also the answer to this question. Both are tagged with [interview](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interview)

Comment: @BenNorris: The linked question *asks* about dress for either faculty or student interviews.  However, none of its *answers* currently addresses student interviews specifically.